# Why is my normalmap rippled and pixelated?

Tags: texturing, export, normals

I've built a high-poly model and manually reduced it to low-poly, by applying the subsurface modifier and merging excess edge loops. I then imported copies of these in .obj format to XNormal, where I rendered a normal map. When applied to the low-poly model in Blender, it recieves these fine, rippling artifacts:

[image: Normal map from XNormal applied to low-poly model in Blender 3D view]
Where do these artifacts come from? How do I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment on answer by cmomoney: Thank you, this was exactly the problem. I applied the Mirror mod and remapped the UV. Now I've got problems with the high-poly poking through, so I'll have to remake the low-poly anyway... but that is beyond this question.

Comment: Have you tried removing doubles and recalculating normals?

Comment: Just did and it looks precisely the same :/

Comment: It could be an ngon face problem.

Comment: Can you upload your file through [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) It will help in troubleshooting your problem

Comment: Try to Retopo-ing the mesh. Maybe reduce the amount of vertices and faces in the area.

Comment: @Grimlock Uploaded :-) I'll hold off on the retopo, this is present across the model

Comment: The image isn't packed with the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *Mirror* modifier on the model on the X and Y axis. So you have four parts UV mapped to the same place after you export( I'm assuming you had the "Apply modifiers" option checked). The artifacts are "layering" caused by the normals being baked four times to the same area. Either apply the modifier and remap the UVs, or export without the modifier applied and bake.